# How to list mssql records in onPostExecute using custom arrayAdapter. I wrote the following codes, but when I execute the app is stopped

Tags: android, sql-server, listview

I want to list my mssql records in android listview. Here is my codes;

activity;

```
public class YoneticiMenuActivity extends Activity {

JSONObject jsonObject = null;
//JSONArray jsonArray = null;
//public Is isler = new Is();
//public ArrayList<Is> arrayIsler = new ArrayList<Is>();
ListView lvTumIsler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yonetici_menu);

    Intent iAl = getIntent();
    String mesaj = iAl.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.m);

    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mSP;
    mSP = getSharedPreferences(mesaj, mode);

    String baslik = mSP.getString("name", "") + " " + mSP.getString("surname", "") + ", Hoşgeldiniz";
    setTitle(baslik);

    lvTumIsler = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTumIsler);
    new AsyncTaskYonetici("Veriler yükleniyor...").execute();
}

private class AsyncTaskYonetici extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String modalMesaj;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    public Is isler = new Is();
    public ArrayList<Is> arrayIsler = new ArrayList<Is>();
    //private ListView lvTumIsler;


    public AsyncTaskYonetici(String mMesaj) {
        this.modalMesaj = mMesaj;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(YoneticiMenuActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage(modalMesaj);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 

        String url = "http://www.saklambacjeans.com/skbos/webServiceTumIsler.aspx";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

                String line = null;
                try {
                    if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(line);                        
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        instream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                    
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Mesaj(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Mesaj(e.getMessage());
        } /*catch (JSONException e) {
            Mesaj(e.getMessage());
        }*/

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void str) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                isler.setP(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("urunId").toString()),
                           Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("modelNo").toString()),
                           jsonObject.getString("modelAd").toString(),
                           jsonObject.getString("bedenAd").toString(),
                           Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("adet").toString()),
                           jsonObject.getString("aciklama").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("kesmeTalimat").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("atolyeTalimat").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("yıkamaTalimat").toString(),
                           jsonObject.getString("utuTalimat").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("kesimci").toString(),
                           jsonObject.getString("atolyeci").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("yıkamacı").toString(), 
                           jsonObject.getString("utucu").toString(), jsonObject.getString("kontrolcu").toString());
                arrayIsler.add(isler);  
            }       
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        IsAdapter adapter = new IsAdapter(YoneticiMenuActivity.this, R.layout.layouttumisler, arrayIsler);
        lvTumIsler.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private void Mesaj(String s) {

    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

my adapter;

```
public class IsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Is> {

private ArrayList<Is> arrayIsler;
Context context;

public IsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Is> a) {

    super(context, layoutResourceId, a);
    this.arrayIsler = a;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layouttumisler, null);
    }

    Is is = arrayIsler.get(position);

    if (is != null) {
        TextView tvId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        TextView tvModel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvModel);
        TextView tvAtolye = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvAtolye);
        TextView tvUrunId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvUrunId);
        TextView tvUrunModel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvUrunModel);
        TextView tvUrunAtolye = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvUrunAtolye);

        if (tvId != null){
            tvId.setText("Ürün No: ");
        }
        if (tvUrunId != null){
            tvUrunId.setText(is.getId());
        }
        if (tvModel != null){
            tvModel.setText("Model: ");
        }
        if (tvUrunModel != null){
            tvUrunModel.setText(is.getModel());
        }
        if (tvAtolye != null){
            tvAtolye.setText("Atolye: ");
        }
        if (tvUrunAtolye != null){
            tvUrunAtolye.setText(is.getAtolye());
        }
    }

    return row;
}
```

}

my Is class;

```
public class Is {
public int urunId;
public int modelNo;
public String modelAd;
public String bedenAd;
public int adet;
public String aciklama;
public String kesmeTalimat;
public String atolyeTalimat;
public String yikamaTalimat;
public String utuTalimat;
public String kesimci;
public String atolyeci;
public String yikamaci;
public String utucu;
public String kontrolcu;

public int getId() {return urunId;}
public String getModel() {return modelAd;}
public String getAtolye() {return atolyeci;}

public void setP(int u, int mN, String mA, String bA, int a, String ac, String kT, String aT, String yT, String uT,
        String k, String at, String y, String utu, String ko)
{
urunId = u;
modelNo = mN;
modelAd = mA;
bedenAd = bA;
adet = a;
aciklama = ac;
kesmeTalimat = kT;
atolyeTalimat = aT;
yikamaTalimat = yT;
utuTalimat = uT;
kesimci = k;
atolyeci = at;
yikamaci = y;
utucu = utu;
kontrolcu = ko;
}
```

}

I use listview in main layout and there is 6 textview in layouttumısler. I use IsAdapter in onPostExecute in myAsyncTask but when I execute the app it is stopped.
The mssql records come from web service truely, But I can not list. I take error in IsAdapter getView, in

```
tvUrunId.setText(is.getId());
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bad mistake, when I change

```
public int getId() {return urunId;}
```

as

```
public String getId() 
{
    String s = Integer.toString(urunId);
    return s;
}
```

the code works.